# Supported interfaces for ink! contracts (like EIP-165)

Tags: ink, smart-contract

Is there a way in ink! to check supported contract interfaces?
EVM has [EIP-165](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-165). I know we have very few PSPs but already the interface information could be useful for PSP34/37 or say RMRK.

What would be the best way forward? Create new PSP?
If new PSP is the answer what can be used in ink! as Solidity [Type Information](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=type#type-information)?

Comment: Hello, I'm encountering similar requirement issues because we are building an explorer for Ink smart contracts. I'd like to inquire whether you've raised the issue or found a solution for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no standardised way of checking contract interfaces. All PSPs are implemented by [OpenBrush](https://github.com/727-Ventures/openbrush-contracts). I would recommend opening the issue there to start the discussion there to introduce another standard.

For type information, you can try using https://docs.rs/type-info/latest/type_info